# Insert new line in pseudo element's content using jQuery data-attributes

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to create a tool-tip using pseudo elements. The content of the tooltip is created in javascript and added to the element's `data-*` attribute using jQuery.

Here is what I am trying: http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/1599/

Javascript:

```
var toolTipText = "Line 1. &#xa; Line 2";

$(element).attr("data-tooltip", toolTipText);
```

CSS:

```
[data-tooltip]:after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    background-color: black;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

After going through many questions in SO, I figured out that:

1. It works this way, if you define the data-attributes directly in html:

   `<span data-tooltip= "Line 1 &#xa; Line 2"></span>`
2. It works using `\A` escape sequence if content is directly written in CSS. ( from [content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content.) property specs)

   `content: 'Line 1. \A Line 2.'`

Please let me help to understand what exactly goes wrong with my jQuery way?

Comment: please use **\\A** instead &#xa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var toolTipText = "Line 1. &#xa; Line 2";
$(element).attr("data-tooltip", $.parseHTML(toolTipText)[0].data)
```

> jQuery.parseHTML uses native methods to convert the string to a set of
>   DOM nodes, which can then be inserted into the document.

Answer (score 0):

use '**\A**' instead

```
$(function(){
var toolTipText = 'This is Line 1. \\A This is Line 2.';
$('#hoverMe').attr('data-tooltip' , toolTipText);

});
```

Comment: did you try this? If yes, can you share me a fiddle? I am not able to get it work. Thanks!

Comment: @escapeVelocity just check with your jsfiddle. 
**This is Line 1. &#xa; This is Line 2.**
replace by **This is Line 1. \\A This is Line 2.**